# Como fazer o repositório de usuário utilizar a propriedade extends?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando fazer um repositório genérico, estou usando MongoDB para isso, tentei importá-lo e utiliza-lo com a propriedade `extends` outras classes, mas não obtive êxito.

O que eu preciso é disponibilizar a classe `Repository` para todos os controllers da aplicação, e todas as funcionalidades que precisam de acesso ao banco de dados devem poder se conectar ao repositório.

Neste cenário o que eu tentei:

```js
// userSchema.js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;


// repository.js
class Repository {
    constructor(dbCollection) {
      this.dbCollection = dbCollection;
    }

    get(_id) {
        return this.dbCollection.findById({ _id });
    }
}

module.exports = Repository;

// user.repository.js
const Repository = require('./repository');

class UserRepository extends Repository {
  constructor(user) {
    super({
      dbCollection: user
    });
  }
}

module.exports = UserRepository;

// UserController.js

const UserRepository = require('./user.repository.js');

class UserController {
    async find(req, res) {
        const user = await UserRepository.get(req.params.id);
        return res.status(200).json(user);       
    }
}
module.exports = new UserController();

// mongo.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectionOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false
};

class Database {
  constructor() {
    this.connect();
  }

  connect() {
    return mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, connectionOptions);
  }
}

module.exports = new Database();
```

Também tentei no controller algo como:

```
const UserRepository = require('./user.repository.js');
    const schemaUser = require('./schemaUser');

    class UserController {
        async find(req, res) {
            const test = new UserRepository(schemaUser)
            const user = await test.get(req.params.id);
            return res.status(200).json(user);       
        }
    }
    module.exports = new UserController();
```

Em ambos os casos sem sucesso. Gostária de fazer algo similar a injeção de dependencias.

Comment: Nao estou lembrado, mas `findById` recebe um objeto? Nao seria o `_id` direto no parametro no mongoose: `this.dbCollection.findById(_id);`?

Comment: E quando voce diz "*sem sucesso*", voce recebe uma mensagem de erro ou apenas nada e retornado na consulta?

Answer (score 1):

Não tens um erro na class:

```
class UserRepository extends Repository {
   constructor(user) {
     super({
       dbCollection: user
     });
   }
}
```

No super estas a passar um objeto não devias passar só o user diretamente? Ou seja:

```
class UserRepository extends Repository {
    constructor(user) {
      super(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Este tipo de resposta pode ser um comentário.